# htaccess localhost - mod-rewrite, htdocs, mamp

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

sorry to be a noob:

I just want to get the following RewriteRule working in my localhost htdocs website:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule "index" "index.php"
```

The mod rewrite is uncommented (in mamp), and I know .htaccess is being looked at because I can cause an error on the page if I want to.

I've been reading through pages and understand Regular Expressions a little bit, 
Somethings I have seen : RewriteBase , SymLinks, RewriteCond and some options in square brackets. Are any of these things why my Rewrite isn't working please?

(I have tried various things)

Thanks. Chris

Comment: You say you want to get the "RewriteRule working" - but what are you trying to do exactly?

Answer (score 1):

I guess, the "Rewrite isn't working" means, that you have a rewrite loop, resulting in a 500 Internal Server Error.

What happens here, is a request for `/index` is rewritten to `index.php`. But the request doesn't end here, because the rewrite engine is started again, this time with `index.php` as the request. Now `index.php` matches the pattern `index` and is rewritten to `index.php`. Again, the rewrite engine is run with `index.php` as the request, until the maximum number of loops is reached and Apache gives up, returning the "500 Internal Server Error".

You can see the loop in [Ruleset Processing](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html#InternalRuleset) following the path starting at

- The request
- Apache receives URI
- RewriteRules -> Yes
- RewriteRule
- Check pattern -> Match
- RewriteCond -> No
- Make substitution
- More rules? -> No
- Uri changed? -> Yes, internal URI

---

You may restrict the `RewriteRule` with a [`RewriteCond`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond), either very specific exclude `index.php`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
```

or more generally apply only when the request doesn't correspond to an existing file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Comment: I want it to move on after this one rule

Comment: I think my whole approach was flawed,